# Add UTM and decimal degree fields to a point file

Tags: qgis, coordinates, utm

I have a point layer with CRS = EPSG:3978-NAD83/Canada Atlas Lambert and projection Canada Lambert Conformal Conic.

I used the field calculator and $x, $y to add "coordinates" which I take to be meters from the equator and prime meridian to the point.

I want to add fields for the points in UTMs (zone, X, Y) and decimal degrees.  I'm not trying to change the projection.  The instructions I've found seem to start with layers in UTM which I cannot use because my layer spans 10 UTM zones.  Still, this should be simple, but can someone tell me how to do it?

Comment: Can you tell us which software you are using?

Comment: Very sorry.  QGIS 3.12.1.

Comment: "The instructions I've found seem to start with layers in UTM..." What instructions? Longitude and Latitude would be easy: x(transform($geometry, 'EPSG:3978', 'EPSG:4326')) and y(transform($geometry, 'EPSG:3978', 'EPSG:4326')). Then you'd need an expression to test the Longitude with 10 conditions to slot the points into their UTM's. That's do-able, but difficult. Can you post up your data?

Comment: To Pointdump: thanks very much.  By instructions, I just meant online videos, manuals, etc.  What you suggested worked to add fields for dec deg.  To get UTMs, I could use a polygon layer of the UTM zones to select points in one zone at a time and then export them to a layer in the correct UTM.  Then I could use $x and $y to get the easting and northing and then transfer them and the zone back to the original layer.  Is that (sort of) what you are suggesting (seems cumbersome)?  I'd be happy to post the data if I can figure out how (this is my first question on Stack Exchange).

Comment: I now see that there are various lat-long to UTM tools online.  Since you showed me how to get dec deg, I think I can just use one of them.  Thanks!

Comment: You can post your data by using a link to WeTransfer, DropBox, MEGA, etc.

Comment: OK, thanks.  I understand now.  I'm think I'm fine on the original question.

Comment: @JonBart Can you please post the answer to your own question below?

Comment: Sure.  Someone on stack exchange said I could get decimal degrees using the field calculator with x(transform($geometry, layer_property(@layer, 'crs'),'EPSG:4326')) and y(transform($geometry, layer_property(@layer, 'crs'),'EPSG:4326')) which I did.  Then I exported the attribute table to a csv file, used an online free app to obtain UTMs, and brought the results back into the original layer.  It worked well EXCEPT that the plots were tilted a little and not quite the right size so I had to adjust them.